# Android TimeZone Listener/Receiver - Not Reaching MainActivity

Tags: java, android, timezone, broadcastreceiver, listener

Objective: Have Android auto-detect timezone (TZ) change in class and have MainActivity receive new TZ.

Current: Manifest is setup, class receives TZ (see item 2 below, Log.E shows new TZ after I change TZ on phone), but MainActivity / onTZChanged not receiving new TZ and not being invoked at all.

Question: How do I get MainActivity to receive new TZ from class?

CODE:

1 - Manifest

```
<receiver
    android:name=".TZChangeReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

2 - Class

```
public class TZChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static TZChangeReceiverListener TZChangeReceiverListener;
    public TZChangeReceiver() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        String localTZ = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
        Log.e (" tzchg ", " got it " + localTZ);
        if (TZChangeReceiverListener != null) {
            TZChangeReceiverListener.onTZChanged(localTZ);
        }
    }
    public static String isConnected() {
        String tzToken= TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
        return tzToken ;
    }
    public interface TZChangeReceiverListener {
        void onTZChanged (String isConnected);
    }
}
```

3 - MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  TZChangeReceiver.TZChangeReceiverListener {

...other code...

    @Override
    public void onTZChanged(String isConnected) {
        isConnected = TZChangeReceiver.isConnected();
        Log.e(" TZ", " isConnected " + isConnected);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I was missing the following in MainActivity

```
MyApplication.getInstance().setTZChangeListener(this);
```

and this is in MyApplication:

```
public void setTZChangeListener(TZChangeReceiver.TZChangeReceiverListener listener) {
//Log.e(geotime + " MyApp: ","SetConnListener");
TZChangeReceiver.TZChangeReceiverListener = listener;
```